# Assembly can't load. System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating a Xamarin.Android app using Xamarin for Visual Studio.

Whenever I try to build the solution I get an error telling me that it couldn't load assembly System.IO.FileSystem and that perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile.

Can anyone suggest how I can get around this?

I'll post the code for whatever file you want to look at.

Comment: are you using a package or library that depends on that class?  You might try installing https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives/

Comment: I'm using the WindowsAzure Storage Package that depends on that class. It's installed, but I'm getting the same error anyway.

Comment: that pkg doesn't appear to support Xamarin either - try https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services/

Comment: @Jason The package installing procedure you mentioned is absolutely working in my case. Thanks for your solution.